Automating the download of GitHub Security Overview
As you utilize GitHub Enterprise one of the features is a Security Overview Dashboard.
This allows you to access information about the detection, remediation and prevention of alerts over a period of time in your Organization and it also allows you to Export CSV with that same information.
My question is, does anyone know if there's a way to automate this?
I've checked in the REST API calls but it doesn't seem to be a call to perform said action:
Organization Rest API
Anyone have any ideas on how this would be possible?
I've created an action using the secret-scanning / codeql / dependabot endpoints to make the calls, but the reports aren't as cohesive as when you download that CSV with the whole information.
